# TopBar and the "height" property?

Tags: css

I am learning CSS, I stuck on the `height` property. For example, in a `topbar`, you use a `height` property or a `padding`?

I have 2 ideas:

I can use the `padding` for example:

```
.topbar-logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 11px 11px;
}
```

or, I could use the `padding` property also?

```
.topbar-logo {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model I'm not CSS expert, but you should take a look at the "CSS Box Model" to better understand how height and padding are related.   Incidentally, I avoid hard coding height when at all possible, relying on the content of the box to determine its height.  Otherwise, different screen or window sizes, font sizes, and PPI can mean that content is cropped or hidden.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend padding, because it adds space to all sides of the element